# Create report with Microsoft Report Viewer PDF/A compliance

Tags: reportviewer, pdfa, localreport

is it possible, with Report Viewer, create a **PDF/A** local report?

Actually, in Visual Studio 2013, .NET Framework 4.5 and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms v.10.0.0.0 (runtime v2.0.50727) my code is

```
 string[] streamids;
 string mimeType;
 string encoding;
 string extension;
 
 LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
 lr.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("xxxx", (DataTable)dtSample));
 lr.ReportPath = reportPath;
 return lr.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

I don't know if this report is PDF/A compliance.

Thanks in advance.
Sara

Comment: I understand, but is possible perhaps set ComplianceLevel in report viewer?